# Jboss wildfly socket leak

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, jboss, wildfly-8

Our enterprise application deployed in Jboss wildfly 8.2. The issue is that after a month of jboss restart, the file system operations slow down to one tenth. I.e. if I had a simple static text file of size 1 GB hosted in my apache, downloading it to my local box would be done in like say 3 mins. But after a month, the same operation takes 30 mins. On restarting the jboss, the issue clears off immediately. There is no significant cpu, memory or IO spike in the system.

The count of open files was close to 5.5 million vs max of 5.7 million. The output of "lsof -p " was showing only 5k records, whereas dumping the entire "lsof" and then grepping the jboss pid shows up a huge number.

*$$$ lsof | wc -l* -> **3552282**

*$$$ lsof | awk '{print $2}' | grep jboss-pid | wc -l* -> **2760622**

Out of the 2.7 million files opened by jboss, 1.2 million is showing up as given below. After a restart of jboss, the open files come down, but this number keeps on increasing and ultimately results in slowness. This definitely points to a socket leak, but how do I debug this further?

*$$$ grep "protocol: TCP" /tmp/lsof.41321 -c -> 
**1203852***

*java       41321 106902    sf-admin 2724u     sock                0,6        0t0 1256280582 protocol: TCP*

*java       41321 106902    sf-admin 2725u     sock                0,6        0t0 1247336438 protocol: TCP*

*java       41321 106902    sf-admin 2726u     sock                0,6        0t0 1247336439 protocol: TCP*

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a great answer for this, but if you can I'd suggest upgrading to WildFly 10 if you can. It looks like there were a few leaks fixed in newer versions of WildFly.

- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-408
- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-239 (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3337)
- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-427

It looks like all these were fixed in WildFly 9 which still allows Java 7 if that's a requirement. WildFly 10 requires Java 8.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading is not an easy option. Instead finding the issue and patching jboss is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this myself to document the analysis.

We ended up replacing the undertow jars manually from the 1.1.8 branch. This along with the "tcp-keep-alive" & "read-timeout" attributes solved the issue for us.

```
undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar  
undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar  
undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Final.jar

<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000" max-post-size="-1" **tcp-keep-alive="true" read-timeout="300000"**/>
```